# TTTableViewController not showing activity status when reloading data

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I'm using a TTTableViewController that loads different data urls when a UISegmentedControl is clicked.

```
currentUrl = [urlList objectAtIndex:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
....
[self invalidateModel];
....
```

it's working fine and when I select a different segmented control my TTTableViewController loads the new data from the currentUrl.

The problem is that I don't get the activity status (the spinning loading overlay) when the new data is loaded.

Is there any method I can call to get the loading when I reload the table data?

Already tried many others method like refresh, reload, invalidateView.. But no luck so far
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by calling

```
[self showLoading:YES];
```

when I invalidate the model, and implementing this in the delegate

```
- (void) didLoadModel:(BOOL)firstTime{
  [self showLoading:NO];
  [super didLoadModel:firstTime];
}
```